# How do I add MMS to an existing MongoDB installation

Tags: monitoring, mongodb

I have installed the MMS agent on a live production server (Ubuntu) and it has not found the existing MongoDB instance running. Is there any way of adding an existing running MongoDB instance to this?

There seems to be options for creating new databases, but not adding existing databases to MMS.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty easy: simply add the ***host instance*** in MMS using add host in the deployment tab. Everything else should work automagically.